# Chartkick graph keeps loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, chartkick

I'm trying to display a simple graph with Chartkick. I've installed the gems chartkick, groupdate, and active_median. I have a model (Client) that I want to test on the graph so I tried it using this line:

```
<%= line_chart Client.group_by_day(:created_at), id: random_chartkick_id %>
```

In my helper I have this method to generate a random ID for the chart

```
def random_chartkick_id
  return 'chart-#'+(Random.rand(10000)).to_s
end
```

I'm using google's jsapi via cdn:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "http://www.google.com/jsapi", "chartkick" %>
```

However, the chart just says "loading". When I type a random number in the data field for creating the chart I get an empty chart. 
What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, just needed to add .count

```
<%= line_chart Client.group_by_day(:created_at).count, id: random_chartkick_id %>
```